# Indices of duplicate lists in a nested list

Tags: python, performance, nested-lists, indices

I am trying to solve a problem that is a part of my genome alignment project. The problem goes as follows:
if given a nested list

`y = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,5,4],[4,2,5],[4,2,5],[1,2,8],[1,2,3]]`

extract indices of unique lists into a nested list again.

For example, the output for the above nested list should be

`[[0,1,7],[2],[3],[4,5],[6]]`.

This is because list `[1,2,3]` is present in `0,1,7th` index positions, `[3,4,5]` in 2nd index position and so on.

Since I will be dealing with large lists, what could be the most optimal way of achieving this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create an dictionary (or OrderedDict if on older pythons). The keys of the dict will be tuples of the sub-lists and the values will be an array of indexes. After looping through, the dictionary values will hold your answer:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

y = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,5,4],[4,2,5],[4,2,5],[1,2,8],[1,2,3]]

lookup = OrderedDict()
for idx,l in enumerate(y):
    lookup.setdefault(tuple(l), []).append(idx)

list(lookup.values())
# [[0, 1, 7], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: _older pythons_ means: In Python 3.6 the order-preserving aspect is working and in Python  3.7 or higher it is guaranteed, see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/2648551) for details.

Comment: This solution is much quicker and elegant then mine, runs much quicker. +1

Comment: This method is very efficient even for large lists. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use list comprehension and range to check for duplicate indexes and append them to `result`.

```
result = []
for num in range(len(y)):
    occurances = [i for i, x in enumerate(y) if x == y[num]]
    if occurances not in result: result.append(occurances)

result
#[[0, 1, 7], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to solve this:

```
import numpy as np

y = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 5, 4],
    [4, 2, 5],
    [4, 2, 5],
    [1, 2, 8],
    [1, 2, 3]
]

# Returns unique values of array, indices of that
# array, and the indices that would rebuild the original array
unique, indices, inverse = np.unique(y, axis=0, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
```

---

Here's a print out of each variable:

```
unique = [
[1 2 3]
[1 2 8]
[3 4 5]
[4 2 5]
[6 5 4]]

indices = [0 6 2 4 3]

inverse = [0 0 2 4 3 3 1 0]
```

If we look at our variable - ***inverse***, we can see that we do indeed get [0, 1, 7] as the index positions for our first unique element [1,2,3], all we need to do now is group them appropriately.

```
new_list = []
for i in np.argsort(indices):
    new_list.append(np.where(inverse == i)[0].tolist())
```

Output:

```
new_list = [[0, 1, 7], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Finally, refs for the code above:

Numpy - [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```
y = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4], [4, 2, 5], [4, 2, 5], [1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 3]]

occurrences = {}

for i, v in enumerate(y):
    v = tuple(v)
    if v not in occurrences:
        occurrences.update({v: []})
    occurrences[v].append(i)

print(occurrences.values())
```